# Truss Analysis Problem

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, solid-mechanics

[image: Diagram]

In this case, L, theta and P are given, there will be 4 reactions at the wall? (2 horizontal and 2 vertical).

$$\begin{align}
\sum F_v &= 0 \therefore F_{v,B} + F_{v,A} = P \\
\sum F_h &= 0 \therefore F_{h,B} = F_{h,A}
\end{align}$$

What will be the tensile stresses along AB and AC?

However, I do not know how to obtain the other 2 equations to solve all the reaction forces at the wall and the tensile stresses? Can anyone please help? One of those equations are from the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As member AB is orthogonal to Point C it cannot impart any vertical reaction, hence Point B provides the only vertical support, and hence has to have a vertical reaction equal to P.

to find point B horizontal reaction, we set the sum of moments about point C equal to zero.

$$\begin{align}
\sum M_C &=0 \\
-PL +F_{h_{B}}H &=0 \\
F_{h_{B}} &= PL/H\text{ pointing left} \\
\therefore F_{h_{C}}&=PL/H\text{ pointing right}
\end{align}$$

tensile stress along AB is:
$$\begin{align}
T&=\dfrac{\sqrt{F_{h_{B}}^2+ F_{v_{b}}^2}}{A} \\
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{(PL/H)^2+P^2}}{A}
\end{align}$$
And I let you do the stress on AC.

Comment: @AndyT, please! sometimes we just miss the other guys' point. As you may know there is many guys who may not have clue and once I saw first you mistook the annotation for supports, I thought you where one of them, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

@AndyT and @kamran explained how to technically solve this question.
I would like to add a short comment about the thing seemed to confuse you the most.

Indeed, there are 4 reactions in this problem. If the triangle was made of a solid body, you would deal with a statically indeterminate problem and find it quite hard to resolve those reactions. However, since we are dealing with a truss, you should examine carefully whether its statically determinate or not:

- The number of unknowns is 6 - the above mentioned 4 reactions + axial
  forces along the truss members
- The number of equation is also 6 - 3 pin joints, each has 2
  equilibrium equations (in X and Y directions)
- Since the number of unknown equals the number of equations - you deal
  with statically determinate problem and can resolve all the
  reactions without dealing with the truss stiffness

Answer (score 0):

Resolve at point A, remembering that in a truss the members only carry axial loads:

- Vertically P = F<sub>AB</sub> * sin theta
- Horizontally F<sub>AB</sub> * cos theta + F<sub>AC</sub> = 0

This gives you the member forces without even needing to worry about the reactions (though they're pretty trivial once you've worked out the member forces).